# Getting Feature from Resource

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

Let's say I have an IResource that identifies an EMF Resource, one way to get my feature is for example:

```
 IResource resource = ChannelModelManager.getInstance().findResourceByGUID(guid);
 Resource emfResource = ChannelUtils.getEMFResource((IFile) resource);
 EObject eObject = emfResource.getContents().get(0);
 String name = (String) eObject.eGet(ChannelPackage.eINSTANCE.getParameterType_Name());
```

This is fine, but is there an easier way to get an EObject I need without resorting to the object list? I saw use of uriFragment, but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ResourceSet.getEObject(URI uri, boolean loadOnDemand)](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet.html#getEObject%28org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI,%20boolean%29)

If you have an object you can find out its URI with [EcoreUtil.getURI(EObject eObject)](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/EcoreUtil.html#getURI%28org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject%29).

Answer (score 0):

In EMF each Resource represents a persisted *document* which contains one or more `EObject`s. Each `EObject` has a unique URI, including a fragment that identifies it within its parent structure (see the Javadocs of [URI](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.9.0/index.html?org/eclipse/emf/common/util/URI.html) and [Resource](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.9.0/index.html?org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/Resource.html) for more details). Once you have a `Resource` you can use `Resource.getEObject(String uriFragment) to locate an individual`EObject`within that`Resource`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an end-to-end example on how to do this? Conceptually I understand how this should work, but I am having issues with uri fragment for my Resource.